# Mudar HTACCESS para Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, htaccess, web.config

Olá,
É possível converter este código HTACCESS para um arquivo Web.config ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Qual o objetivo dessa conversão?

Comment: Estou colocando uma aplicação PHP em um servidor Windows 2008 e o ISAPI que faria a tradução do HTACCESS para o servidor não está funcionando, então acredito que se eu conseguir colocar diretamente no Web.config funcione.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

[Há este guia na página do IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig) para a tradução do conteúdo de um arquivo `.htaccess` em um arquivo `Web.config`. Não vale a pena esmiuçar os exemplos contidos no site nesta resposta.

Para o seu caso, em que há reescrita de endereços, [o seguinte link também pode ajudar](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules).

No exemplo passado, ficaria algo assim:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Regra 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?route={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Não testei essa configuração. Apenas fiz a tradução baseado no conteúdo da pergunta.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo!